# Only a DB Class or a Combo Group (DB Class + Results Class)

Tags: php, mysql, class

my questions pertain to class objects defined for mysql/php interface:

Which of the following method is best from a design point and why (relative advantages/disadvantages to each other):

1. To use a single class like ezSQL towards abstracting the mysql/php interface?
2. To use a combination of a DB Connection Class and a Results Class?

Say, I want to build a search engine, where I would have to add links, attach a picture to each result, provide a link to edit that entry etc., should I use single class like ezSQL or a combo of DB Class and Results Class?

Also, whether the Results Class should be defined to represent an object covering the entire resultset or an object representing a single result from the entire resultset? Would there be any significant performance difference between the two for a database of 2 million entries and concurrent 500 queries?

Another related question:

3) For option 2 above, should the result loop be placed within a function in the Results Class to give all the results or the result loop should be outside the Class?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a DB connection class and result set classes are all necessary. Actually, it depends on the complexity of your application, usually each DB table may have a class and a DAO class for the table's processing. Usually, I will use a class to match a single row in the table and just use array of the objects to represent the whole result set. The table class is kind of a structure in C, just with variables to the table columns. The loop etc.. you asked in 3) should in be the DAO class